# wp_list_categories - add class to list items

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming, categories

I am trying to style my wordpress category listing to add a class of `list-group-item` to each li element as follows:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item cat-item cat-item-12"><a href="..." title="View all posts filed under ...">...</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item cat-item-14"><a href="..." title="View all posts filed under ...">...</a></li>
</ul>
```

Extending the **WP_Widget_Categories** Class

```
Class GdCategoriesWidget extends WP_Widget_Categories {

function widget( $args, $instance ) {

        // Most of widget method deleted out for S/O readability.

    ?>
    <ul class="list-group">
<?php
    $cat_args['title_li'] = '';

    wp_list_categories( apply_filters( 'widget_categories_args', $cat_args ) );
?>
        </ul>

    // After Widget stuff deleted out for S/O readability

}
```

De-registering original and registering my custom widget

```
function gd_widget_registration() {
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Categories');
    register_widget('GdCategoriesWidget');
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'gd_widget_registration');
```

The problem that I am facing is that I cannot see anywhere in the docs http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Markup_and_Styling_of_Category_Lists where I can override the class applied to list items.

Comment: Check this; http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115526/add-class-to-items-in-wp-list-categories

Comment: Thanks for that!!! Works like a charm! Wish it was customisable out of the box though! No answers will be accepted as @NikkiMather has provided solution in attached link.